# EF: Can I delete the setter from ID property?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

It seams to me axiomatic that there is no need for the setter, though I never saw anyone mention it, but every developer using it.
Isn't it better and clearer to delete this portion since I don't set the ID and it's auto-generated:

```
public int ID { get; }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate [Can private setters be used in an entity model?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26768695/1260204)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's generated by the database, then it will be assigned by Entity Framework to the entity. So it needs a setter.

You can also attach entities by their primary key, so it needs to be publicly settable by user code as well.