# Removing setter from Model Id

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Following [this tutorial from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api) gives me this Model for a TodoItem:

```
namespace TodoApi.Models
{
    public class TodoItem
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string? Content { get; set; }
        public bool Completed { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I do not want the user to be able to update or set the `Id` property. My colleauge solved this by creating a separate model for posting and putting `TodoItem`s - following some tutorial online I think. My idea was to just remove the setter from the property, and after testing the only error I got was that I had to set a PrimaryKey for the Model. I ended up with this:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace TodoApi.Models
{
    [PrimaryKey(nameof(TodoItem.Id))]
    public class TodoItem
    {
        public long Id { get; }
        public string? Content { get; set; }
        public bool Completed { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The code worked, but since I am new and learning I want to know if this is a no-no or if this is okay to do. I cannot find anyone else doing the same online so I thought I'd ask here. Thanks in advance :)

**Edit:** I now see that the put method returns a `400 Bad Request`, so I gues that means it's a no-no? What would be the best way to solve this issue, is it to create a separate model? Or maybe define a setter which doesn't do anything?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [EF: Can I delete the setter from ID property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40402923/ef-can-i-delete-the-setter-from-id-property)

Comment: @tbhaxor Hi, thank you, sort of. My question then is in the edit. What sould I do in this situation? Do I need to create a separate Model for creating/updating items?

Comment: Use a Backing Field. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/backing-field?tabs=data-annotations

Answer (score 0):

You could make a constructor to set initial values and make the setter for Id private.

```
public class TodoItem
{
    public long Id { get; private set; }
    public string? Content { get; set; }
    public bool Completed { get; set; }

    public TodoItem(long id, string? content, bool completed)
    {
        Id = id;
        Content = content;
        Completed = completed;
    }
}
```

### Edit

You could make the setter not actually set:

```
public class TodoItem
{
    private long _id;
    public long Id
    {
        get => _id;
        set {}
    }
    public string? Content { get; set; }
    public bool Completed { get; set; }
}
```

In this case you would probably not get an error because there is a setter but it would also not change the Id.

Comment: Hi, I don't know if you saw the edit but I have now tried your solution and the PUT-method still gives me a 400 Bad Request

Comment: ohh, yes i didn't read your edit.

Comment: In that case you would probably need to create a separate method or model that can handle this.

Comment: @Kris10an Ok, i have added a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

in practice, we use a readmodel that has private set for its properties to avoid unwanted state changes and a write model with an accessible set that updates or creates the persisted data, you can also pass by a viewModel that exposes only the state of your entity and a DTO to CRUD your data