# If property is not set, show warning / error in visual studio?

Tags: c#, .net

I have model classes with properties that have public get/sets because they are written to / from into a db.

I also have a factory to create these models because the initiation and underlying structure is too complicated to create manually each time.

My factory has exception handling if some properties were not set.

So this is just a theoretical question. If someone wold be able to create this model by hand (not possible because it is internal to the factory) / with the factory and one required property is not set. e.g.

```
Model model = new Model() {A = a, B = b, D = d} //C is missing
```

Is it possible to have maybe an attribute or something else, so the editor (visual studio) will already show a warning / error? Instead of having to run the code and hit the exception?

Comment: Use a custom constructor that forces values to be passed in.

Comment: A constructor would enforce that at compile time

Comment: _"with properties that have public get/sets because they are written to / from into a db"_ Why you need public setters? I don't get it. You should enforce correctness with an appropriate constructor.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I believe Entity Framework (for example) requires public setters

Comment: @David: Could be (or deserialization). Anyway, there is no attribute that would  warn you at compile time. Even if there was one, you could always change them at runtime(with public setters) to "unitialize" these properties.

Comment: @DavidG EF doesn't require public setters. Private setters and even a private constructor works just as well, but is of course more...private.

Comment: @Niko Ah yes [you are correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26768809/1663001), but there are other situations (e.g. serialisation perhaps) that might require public setters/constructors.

Comment: Yes, we need it for serialization.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this question highlights the interesting problems you get when you leave POCO data transfer objects exposed in your model layer. Typically, an ORM system imposes constraints on your dtos that aren't necessarily compatible with the encapsulation you want.

What this means is typically that you need the properties to have public setters (for instance), but that this breaks the encapsulation you would want to have on the creation of a new model object (where you would want to have a constructor with specific require parameters).

One possible solution to this is to use inversion of control to isolate your domain model layer from your data persistence layer. This is quite a heavyweight solution, but it basically lets you add whatever code you want to your models, while keeping the implementation details of persistence away from the business logic. It also has the advantage that your business layer doesn't need to depend on your database technology.

Note: Depending on the persistence framework, this is not necessarily to only way to achieve the OP's desire, but this works for any persistence framework, and indeed makes it possible to mix and match easily - so you can serve business objects from multiple data sources and technologies without the use code needing to be aware, and without special considerations in the business logic.

**EDIT**

The pattern I use for this is probably overkill for most uses - it does benefit from complete isolation though - I was able to take a live website and refactor the backend from using EF to using CosmosDB without changing any model code using this approach. If you don't have the requirements of technology isolation, or being able to mix persistence technologies, this is probably going to far:

Example of use:

```
/// <summary>
/// Example of use.
/// </summary>
public static class UseExample
{
    public static BusinessObjectX DoStuff(BusinessObjectXRepoAbstraction repo)
    {
        var newBox = repo.CreateX("mandatory property");
        //Do stuff...
        return newBox;
    }
}
```

Definitions in the business model layer.

```
/// <summary>
/// Persistence Technology independent BO.
/// </summary>
public abstract class BusinessObjectX
{
    internal BusinessObjectX()
    {
    }

    public abstract string SomeProperty { get; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Technology independent repository abstraction for BOX - Create could
/// be a static member of <see cref="BusinessObjectX"/>
/// </summary>
public abstract class BusinessObjectXRepoAbstraction
{
    public abstract BusinessObjectX Create(string mandatoryPropertyValue);
}
```

Definitions in the database layer.

```
    /// <summary>
/// Actual database repository facade for BOX
/// </summary>
internal sealed class BusinessObjectXDatabaseRepo
{
    public BusinessObjectXPoco CreateNew()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("Create in database and return POCO");
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// ORM Poco for BOX.
/// </summary>
internal sealed class BusinessObjectXPoco
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Implementation of business logic layer (depends on both other layers):

```
/// <summary>
/// Facade implementation in terms of a particular POCO and database technology.
/// </summary>
internal sealed class BusinessObjectXImpl : BusinessObjectX
{
    private readonly BusinessObjectXPoco poco;

    internal BusinessObjectXImpl(BusinessObjectXPoco poco)
    {
        this.poco = poco;
    }

    public override string SomeProperty => poco.SomeProperty;
}

/// <summary>
/// Allows the lookup of <see cref="BusinessObjectX"/> instances 
/// from POCOs - has the lifecycle of a transaction.
/// </summary>
internal sealed class BusinessObjectXFacadeLookup
{
    private readonly Func<BusinessObjectXPoco, BusinessObjectX> createFunc;
    private readonly Dictionary<Guid, BusinessObjectXImpl> lookup 
        = new Dictionary<Guid, BusinessObjectXImpl>();

    public BusinessObjectXFacadeLookup(Func<BusinessObjectXPoco, BusinessObjectX> createFunc)
    {
        this.createFunc = createFunc;
    }

    public BusinessObjectX GetOrCreate(BusinessObjectXPoco poco)
    {
        BusinessObjectXImpl ret;
        if (!lookup.TryGetValue(poco.Id, out ret))
        {
            ret = new BusinessObjectXImpl(poco);
            lookup.Add(poco.Id, ret);
        }
        return ret;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Technology specific repository implementation.
/// </summary>
internal sealed class BusinessObjectXRepoConcrete : BusinessObjectXRepoAbstraction
{
    private readonly BusinessObjectXDatabaseRepo databaseRepo;
    private readonly BusinessObjectXFacadeLookup lookup;

    public BusinessObjectXRepoConcrete(BusinessObjectXDatabaseRepo databaseRepo, 
        BusinessObjectXFacadeLookup lookup)
    {
        this.databaseRepo = databaseRepo;
        this.lookup = lookup;
    }

    public override BusinessObjectX Create(string mandatoryPropertyValue)
    {
        var poco = databaseRepo.CreateNew();
        poco.SomeProperty = mandatoryPropertyValue;
        return lookup.GetOrCreate(poco);
    }
}
```

Comment: In other words you would use 2 models instead of one. Both using the same Interface?

Comment: No. This approach is probably overkill for most uses, I'll edit my answer with some code.

Comment: In terms of how it helps with the original question, there is exactly one way to create a BOX, with the exact required parameters. So it isn't possible to miss one, and this is checked at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

Decouple your model as DTO and ORM model and DTO will handle all validation and ORM model used for DB mapping.

For DTO validation we can use different approach like.

1. Parameterized constructor
2. Attribute the property as Required and validate model with a Generic Approach like model.Validate() (But No Visual studio prompt )
3. Extent code analysis with model required property rule (custom rule) and it would trigger before run time.

Regards

Abdul

Comment: I downvoted this answer because it advocates runtime validation - whereas the OP is after _compile-time_ guarantees that properties are being set or raises a compiler warning.